# div shifts to the bottom of the page with any content

Tags: css

I am attempting to put together a web page that has four areas: a header, footer, content, and controls. The header and footer should be fixed at the top and bottom of the page (respectively) and automatically size to their content. The controls should go on the far right side of the page (vertically between the header and footer) and is fixed-width. The content area should fill the remainder of the page.

I had this working, but now whenever I add any kind of content (even just a single-word paragraph element), the controls area moves to almost the very bottom of the page. You can see what I'm referring to here: http://jsfiddle.net/ym8vY/1/

If I leave the controls `div` completely empty, it lays out exactly how I want it: http://jsfiddle.net/ym8vY/

My `body` currently looks like:

```
<header>
    <p>Header</p>
</header>
<div class="main">
    <div id="streamGraph" class="page">
        <div class="page-row">
            <div class="page-content-container-outer">
                <div class="page-content-container-inner">
                    <div id="graphContainer" class="page-content"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="page-controls-container-outer">
                <div class="page-controls-container-inner">
                    <div class="page-controls"><!-- If anything goes inside here, it breaks -->
                        <div style="display: table; height: 100%;"> 
                            <div style="display: table-row; height: 0;">
                                <div>
                                    <label for="sampleCount"># Samples:</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="sampleCount" name="sampleCount" value="100" />
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <label for="tagCount"># Tags:</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="tagCount" name="tagCount" value="25" />
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <label for="fromDate">From:</label>
                                    <input type="date" id="fromDate" name="fromDate" />
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <label for="toDate">To:</label>
                                    <input type="date" id="toDate" name="toDate" />
                                </div>
                                <button id="tagsButton">Customize Tags</button>
                                <button id="refreshButton">Apply</button>
                            </div>
                            <div style="display: table-row;">
                                <div id="tagContainer" style="overflow: auto; height: 100%;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    <p>Footer</p>
</footer>
```

And my CSS is:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    display: table;
}
header, .main, footer {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}
header, footer {
    background: lightgray;
}
.main {
    height: 100%;
}
.page {
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.page-row {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}
.page-content-container-outer {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}
.page-controls-container-outer {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}
.page-content-container-inner {
    border: solid;
    border-color: gainsboro;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
}
.page-controls-container-inner {
    border: solid;
    border-color: gainsboro;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
}
.page-controls {
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
}
.page-content {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Downvoter care to comment? CSS and HTML isn't my usual fare, so if I'm missing some expected information I'll be happy to add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your right-side div is being pushed down to the baseline. Add `vertical-align:top` to fix it:

```
div
{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ym8vY/2/)

---

**Side note:** The default value for `vertical-align` is baseline. Always keep this in mind when using cells and inline-blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align:top;` to your `.page-controls-container-outer` class

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<div style="display: table-row; height: 0;">
```

to this

```
 <div style="display: table-row; height: 0; float:left;">
```